# Loading projection along with raster in R?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, import

Why the operation `myraster = raster("test.asc")` does not load the associated projection file test.prj located in the same directory as test.asc?

Does `raster()` need a specific argument? It seems impractical that I have to manually set the projection when it's already defined.

Comment: Although this would be convenient, it seems a little risky to assume that any file whatsoever, such as a generic .asc file, should be associated with any other .prj file found in the same directory. But as a workaround, why not load the raster once, assign the desired projection to it, and save it in a format in which the projection information is reliably stored?  (The specific answer to your question is found in the help page for `Raster::raster`, which does not appear to document any such optional argument.)

Comment: @whuber sorry but I completely disagree, a .prj file with the same name as the raster files its associated with its 99% the correct .prj file. There shouldn't be any extra steps just to load a string of characters.

Comment: This should work as illustrated below by xunilk. Perhaps you need to update R and or rgdal (and perhaps gdal if you are not on windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to read the projection of an .asc file with a .prj file associated.

Below, there is a reproducible example, so you can try to figure out what is different regarding your .prj file. Step 3 shows the .asc file imported with a projection assigned.

```
#load necessary packages
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

#---------------------------
#Step 1: Create raster, write .asc file, and check projection when importing it back.

#Generate raster with projection
r <- raster(list(x = 1:nrow(volcano), 
                 y = 1:ncol(volcano), 
                 z = volcano), 
            crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=-50 +datum=WGS84")

#Write the .asc file.
writeRaster(r, "C:\\teste\\file.asc")

#Import the .asc file
r2 = raster("C:\\teste\\file.asc") #assume the name of the .asc file to be "file", and that it is stored under directory "C:\teste".
#check prjection of RasterLayer object
r2@crs
CRS arguments: NA #no projection

#---------------------------    
#Step 2: Create .prj file from a dummy shapefile
# This step is a code adapted from Michael Sumner's answer (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-July/019023.html)

#Create SpatialPolygons object
dummy <- as(extent(r), "SpatialPolygons")
#Assign same projection from RasterLayer object "r"
proj4string(dummy) <- CRS(proj4string(r))

#Write the dummy shapefile
writeOGR(SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(dummy, data.frame(x = 1)), dsn="C:\\teste", "file", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
#Discard files other than .prj
unlink(c("C:\\teste\\file.shp", "C:\\teste\\file.shx", "C:\\teste\\file.dbf"))

#---------------------------    
#Step 3 - Import the .asc file having the corresponding .prj file.

#Import .asc file
r2 = raster("C:\\teste\\file.asc")
#check projection of RasterLayer object
r2@crs
CRS arguments:
 +proj=laea +lat_0=-50 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: To write a prj file, you can do:   writeLines(showWKT(crs(x, asText=TRUE)), extension(filename, 'prj') )    where x is the Raster object with a crs, and filename is the ascii file you are writing to. Hence most of the steps shown above can be omitted.

Comment: @AndreSilva. Yes you are right; i misunderstood your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Aparently, it doesn't. I tested it in my system (see next image):

[image]

However, I revised the 'raster' package documentation and it suggests the installation of 'rgdal' library. I have rgdal installed. Do you have it?

**Editing Note**:

I tested, based in the Andre Silva answer, that the 'writeRaster' method did not write a *.prj file with the AIIGrid driver. However,  the raster object 'r' has a projection. It was corroborated when the 'writeRaster' method was used  with the GTiff driver (and the raster loaded in QGIS):

```
> writeRaster(r,'prueba.asc',drivername='AIIGrid')
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 256, 280, 71680  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 679125, 687525, 965265, 972945  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : /home/zeito/proyectosR/prueba.asc 
names       : prueba

> writeRaster(r,'prueba.tif',drivername='GTiff')
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 256, 280, 71680  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 679125, 687525, 965265, 972945  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=19 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /home/zeito/proyectosR/prueba.tif 
names       : prueba 
values      : 463, 3414  (min, max)
```

Comment: yes I do have rgdal installed and loaded but my raster is loaded without projection

Comment: It's very strange. It works well in my Debian Linux System.

Comment: Could the * .prj be empty or bad named? Why do not it open?

Comment: the file is not empty it contains this string GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Comment: Test something as this (to force loading the *.prj): `s<-raster('b3_c.asc', crs='b3_c.asc.prj')`. I got:

`In .getProj(attr(gdalinfo, "projection"), crs) :
  argument "crs" ignored because the file provides a crs`